# Category navigation in navigation child

Tags: php, magento, navigation, categories

I have a problem with navigation in Magento. The child categories displays in a funny way, which i do not want them too. Please see the following screenshot:

http://tinypic.com/r/2l97byp/8

In upper left, the childs are shown in the menu. However i do not want them to expanding into a new block, but simply show below their parrent category as seen in this picture:

tinypic.com/r/16l0kk3/8

I have two sets of code for this, however i do not know what to edit to get the desired result. I have tried to get it to work, but with no luck.

The two code parts:

top.phtml:

```
<?php
/**
 * Top menu for store
 *
 * @see Olegnax_Navigation_Block_Navigation
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml() supports optional arguments:
 * int Level number for list item class to start from
 * string Extra class of outermost list items
 * string If specified wraps children list in div with this class
 */
?>
<!-- navigation BOF -->
<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0, 'level-top', 'sub-wrapper' ) ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<nav class="olegnax">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('celebritysettings/celebritysettings_header/navigation_home')): ?>
         <li class="level0 level-top">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(); ?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Home'); ?></span></a>
         </li>
     <?php endif; ?>
        <?php
        echo $_menu;
        $custom_tab = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('celebrity_navigation_block');
        if($custom_tab->getIsActive()) {
            echo '
            <li class="level0 level-top parent custom-block">
                <a href="#" class="level-top">
                    <span>'.$custom_tab->getTitle().'</span>
                </a>
                <div class="sub-wrapper">'.$this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('celebrity_navigation_block')->toHtml().'</div>
            </li>';
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
<?php endif ?>
<!-- navigation EOF -->
```

And Navigation.phtml:

```
    <?php
/**
 * @version   1.0 12.0.2012
 * @author    Olegnax http://www.olegnax.com <mail@olegnax.com>
 * @copyright Copyright (C) 2010 - 2012 Olegnax
 */

class Olegnax_Navigation_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation
{

    /**
     * columns html
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_columnHtml;

    /**
     * Render category to html
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
     * @param int Nesting level number
     * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is last, affects list item class
     * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is first, affects list item class
     * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is outermost, affects list item class
     * @param string Extra class of outermost list items
     * @param string If specified wraps children list in div with this class
     * @param boolean Whether ot not to add on* attributes to list item
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml($category, $level = 0, $isLast = false, $isFirst = false,
        $isOutermost = false, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $noEventAttributes = false)
    {
        if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
            return '';
        }
        $html = array();

        // get all children
        if (Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat')->isEnabled()) {
            $children = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
            $childrenCount = count($children);
        } else {
            $children = $category->getChildren();
            $childrenCount = $children->count();
        }
        $hasChildren = ($children && $childrenCount);

        // select active children
        $activeChildren = array();
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if ($child->getIsActive()) {
                $activeChildren[] = $child;
            }
        }
        $activeChildrenCount = count($activeChildren);
        $hasActiveChildren = ($activeChildrenCount > 0);

        // prepare list item html classes
        $classes = array();
        $classes[] = 'level' . $level;
        $classes[] = 'nav-' . $this->_getItemPosition($level);
        if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        }
        $linkClass = '';
        if ($isOutermost && $outermostItemClass) {
            $classes[] = $outermostItemClass;
            $linkClass = ' class="'.$outermostItemClass.'"';
        }
        if ($isFirst) {
            $classes[] = 'first';
        }
        if ($isLast) {
            $classes[] = 'last';
        }
        if ($hasActiveChildren) {
            $classes[] = 'parent';
        }

        // prepare list item attributes
        $attributes = array();
        if (count($classes) > 0) {
            $attributes['class'] = implode(' ', $classes);
        }
        if ($hasActiveChildren && !$noEventAttributes) {
             $attributes['onmouseover'] = 'toggleMenu(this,1)';
             $attributes['onmouseout'] = 'toggleMenu(this,0)';
        }

        // assemble list item with attributes
        $htmlLi = '<li';
        foreach ($attributes as $attrName => $attrValue) {
            $htmlLi .= ' ' . $attrName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attrValue) . '"';
        }
        $htmlLi .= '>';
        $html[] = $htmlLi;

        $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
        $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
        $html[] = '</a>';

        if ( $level == 0 ) {
            //get category description
            $ca = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
            $description = $ca->getDescription();
            if ( empty($description) || !Mage::getStoreConfig('celebritysettings/celebritysettings_navigation/show_description') ) {
                $columns = 4;
            } else {
                $columns = 2;
            }
            $columnItemsNum = array_fill(0, $columns, floor($activeChildrenCount / $columns));
            if ( $activeChildrenCount % $columns > 0 ) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < ($activeChildrenCount % $columns); $i++ ) {
                    $columnItemsNum[$i]++;
                }
            }
            $this->_columnHtml = array();
        }

        // render children
        $htmlChildren = '';
        $j = 0; //child index
        $i = 0; //column index
        $itemsCount = $columnItemsNum[$i];
        foreach ($activeChildren as $child) {

            if ( $level == 0 ) {
                $isLast = (($j+1) == $itemsCount || $j == $activeChildrenCount - 1);
                if ( $isLast ) {
                    $i++;
                    $itemsCount += $columnItemsNum[$i];
                }
            } else {
                $isLast = ($j == $activeChildrenCount - 1);
            }

            $childHtml = $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(
                $child,
                ($level + 1),
                $isLast,
                ($j == 0),
                false,
                $outermostItemClass,
                $childrenWrapClass,
                $noEventAttributes
            );
            if ( $level == 0 ) {
                $this->_columnHtml[] = $childHtml;
            } else {
                $htmlChildren .= $childHtml;
            }
            $j++;
        }

        if ( $level == 0 && $this->_columnHtml ) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ( $columnItemsNum as $columnNum ) {
                $chunk = array_slice($this->_columnHtml, $i, $columnNum);
                $i += $columnNum;
                $htmlChildren .= '<li '.(count($this->_columnHtml) == $i ? 'class="last"' : '').'><ol>';
                foreach ( $chunk as $item ) {
                    $htmlChildren .= $item;
                }
                $htmlChildren .= '</ol></li>';
            }
        }
        if ( !empty($description) && !empty($htmlChildren) && Mage::getStoreConfig('celebritysettings/celebritysettings_navigation/show_description') ) {
            $htmlChildren .= '<li class="menu-category-description clearfix">'.$description;
            if ( Mage::getStoreConfig('celebritysettings/celebritysettings_navigation/show_learn_more') ) {
                $htmlChildren .= '<p><button class="button" onclick="window.location=\''.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'\'"><span><span>'.$this->__('learn more').'</span></span></button></p>';
            }
            $htmlChildren .= '</li>';
        }

        if (!empty($htmlChildren)) {
            if ($childrenWrapClass) {
                $html[] = '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
            }
            $html[] = '<ul class="level' . $level . '">';
            $html[] = $htmlChildren;
            $html[] = '</ul>';
            if ($childrenWrapClass) {
                $html[] = '</div>';
            }
        }

        $html[] = '</li>';

        $html = implode("\n", $html);
        return $html;
    } }
```

I hope someone can see what to do in order to get the effect on the image :)

Best Regards,
Patrick

Comment: You've basically asked two different questions here: How does Magento category displaying code work, and how to I achieve a specific layout effect in a random website's CSS/HTML code.  Both questions are pretty broad in and of themselves.  Together, I doubt you'll get the answer you're looking for.

Comment: This is a pretty specific question. As far as i can see, this has nothing to do with my websites CSS, as this is all done in the top.phtml. This is a question about how to achieve the desired effect as shown in the pictures using the two code files in my question. I have tried many different changes, but without luck.

The question relates very closely to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395096/magento-categories-and-products-in-navigation-child , but no help was found there either.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Alan Storm is correct but for what it is worth, to answer your question 'which file do I edit', the file you edit is Navigation.php. I say this because top.phtml has the line `echo $_menu;`. Anyway, the code in `protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()` is perhaps a little convoluted and when I read the code and think about what you are trying to achieve I think you should either:

a) Try commenting out the lines:

```
if ($hasActiveChildren && !$noEventAttributes) {
     $attributes['onmouseover'] = 'toggleMenu(this,1)';
     $attributes['onmouseout'] = 'toggleMenu(this,0)';
}
```

in order to remove the mouseover interaction and then see if you can hack the CSS to get the layout you desire

or

b) Throw away all the code in `protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()` and start again: rewrite it to display the HTML structure you require using elements of the existing code.